# Displaying Date Created for Users in .NET Admin view

Tags: .net, datetime, kendo-ui

I'm 2 months into being a .NET developer, and this is my first post. FYI. I did my best to research this problem, but I did not have any luck. Thanks in advance, and I'll try to be as detailed as possible.

The site I am working on has an admin page, and in the admin page, there is a button that goes to a Manage Users view. Inside that view the administrator can Create a New User or view/manage a list of Users. The problem that the customer has: the view does not show when the user was created on the grid. Here is what I have tried to do so far.

First, I added the following dateCreated code to the bottom of the `AdminUserListViewModel`:

```
[Display(Name = "Date Created")]
private DateTime? dateCreated;
public DateTime DateCreated
{
   get { return dateCreated ?? DateTime.UtcNow; }
   set { dateCreated = value; }
}
```

Second, I added code to the Index of my User view. The app is using Kendo, so I looked at both the Kendo documentation and Stack and found this code for displaying DateTime in a Kendo grid:
    `columns.Bound(b => b.DateCreated).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(CreatedDate), 'dd/MM/yyyy') #");`

Third, I added the following code to the UserService in my Create User method:

```
DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow
```

Fourth, here is my method for creating the list.

```
public List<AdminUserListViewModel> GetAll()
{
using (var context = Dependencies.AppDataContext)
{
    var result = (
    from r in context.Users
    join u in context.UNUsers on r.Id equals   
    u.ApplicationUserId.ToString()
    select new AdminUserListViewModel
{
    Username = r.UserName,
    ....
    DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow, 
}).ToList();
return result;
}
}
```

Current result when running locally: 
A column has been created with the date and time, but the date and time are always set to the current date and time rather than when the User was created. Make sense? If this isn't clear, I can provide more information. Thanks!

Comment: kendo.parseDate(CreatedDate) , did you mean DateCreated?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes. I changed it to DateCreated. Appears to be the same result though.

Comment: It might help if you post the code that provides the AdminUserListViewModels

Comment: I posted the relevant parts of the method above. (I think)

Comment: So it basically looks like you are not persisting the DateCreated property to your database. In any case you aren't reading it from your database.

Comment: Thank you, Robbert. Your answer helped me learn to do a SQL query and check the DB for what is happening(remember I'm new). It does appear that the correct date and time are showing in SSMS. It's still coming back as the current date though. I'll work on it more today and let you know. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If Your problem is that grid displays current date instead of item creation date, You should look at query for getting data.

You assign current date instead of getting it from database:

```
public List<AdminUserListViewModel> GetAll()
{
using (var context = Dependencies.AppDataContext)
{
    var result = (
    from r in context.Users
    join u in context.UNUsers on r.Id equals   
    u.ApplicationUserId.ToString()
    select new AdminUserListViewModel
{
    Username = r.UserName,
    ....
    DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow, <== HERE: DateCreated = r.DateCreated
}).ToList();
return result;
}
}
```